# Tool to show relations and property values of ABox of Ontology

Tags: visualization, owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I am looking for a tool that allows for visualization of the Abox of an ontology.
I am familiar with Protégé (also OntoGraf and OWLVis) and (Web)-VOWL as Ontology visualization tools.
But none of those shows the Abox (Individuals and Relations) in detail. They only list individuals. I am interested in showing the relations between the individuals and their property values. Is there a tool that can do this ?

Comment: They only list individuals. --> They only list classes / concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my "reputation" is not high enough to be allowed to post a comment, so I'll just somewhat abuse the answer field to share my comment and/or incomplete answer anyways.

I am also looking for a tool for visualizing OWL ABox axioms, but I have not been able to find anything that is ready for immediate use.  A DDG search turned up an article from 2006, [Interactive Visualization of Large OWL Instance Sets](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.090/Publikationen/2006/swui06-noppens.pdf) that talks about a tool called [GROWL](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3199354), but it looks like it was also not much more than a paper from the mid 2000s.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Use the OWL and/or Protege APIs to create a tool or extend an existing one to visualize ABox axioms.
2. Convert your instances to RDF and use a tool for visualizing RDF graphs.

The second option seems like a lot less work, so I'm looking into doing it that way.

Also, have you looked at [OWLGrEd](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/)?  The desktop version seems to be capable of visualizing ABox axioms with a bit more detail than the others, but there's not a lot of tools to do further manipulation of your selections.